# Get only common records like inner join in Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I have `two tables` `Sections` and `Categories`

### Sections

```
section id       section name
```

### Category

```
category id      section id          category name
```

basic foreign key structure. So I want to `get records of all Sections with categories but only those sections which have a child category record`. Normally you would use inner join but i'm new to eloquent. I'm getting all the sections and categories like a left join but i don't want that.

**in Section Model**

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Obonce\Category','section_id');
    }


public function getSections()
    {
        $sections = Sections::find(1)->with(['category'])->get();
        return $sections;
    }
```

How to `get records that are common for section and category`? Btw i haven't created a foreign key in db just a virtual fk structure. Would that cause an issue with this type of relations?

Comment: You actually want the all caterories for each section. right ?

Comment: yeah but some sections don't have categories right now so i dont want to fetch those sections. So there might be 3 sections but only need to fetch 1 because it has child categories.

Comment: Thanks that worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Section::has('category')->get();`
Just check the following link https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations **Querying Relationship Existence** section.